# Getting Datagridview value

Tags: .net, vb.net

Using VB.Net,

In my application, am using datagridview, when i clicking the particular row, that rows value should be appear in the textbox.

So the code should be come under the DataGrid3_CellMouseDoubleClick Event.

How to dispaly a rows value in the textbox.

For Example

3 rows means - 3 rows values should display in 3 textbox.

vb6 code

```
Private Sub datagrid1_DblClick()

    textbox1 = datagrid1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)
    textbox2 = datagrid1.SelectedItem.SubItems(2)
    textbox3 = datagrid1.SelectedItem.SubItems(3)
End Sub
```

How to write a code in vb.net by getting datagrid row values.

Need VB.Net sample code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ->

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
Dim i As Integer
i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
End Sub
```

Here i is the RowIndex of the selected row for `DataGridView1.Item(0, i),` and the number is the cell index.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through the rows and cells of your datagridview in order to get the values.

Something like this:

```
if (datagrid1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < datagrid1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
     {
          DataGridViewRow gridRow = datagrid1.SelectedRows[i];
          textbox1 = gridRow.Cells[0].Value;
          textbox2 = gridRow.Cells[1].Value;
          textbox3 = gridRow.Cells[2].Value;
     }
}
```

I assume you want the selected rows only. If not should be easy to just loop through all of them. Also I am not sure how to convert it to VB.NET but am sure you can see what I am trying to do.